# Different version of ReportViewer component in the same application

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, reportviewer

In my company i have an application which should run at two different sites with different database configuration.
At one site we have Sql Server 2008 R2, at the other one Sql Server 2005; we cannot upgrade the Sql Server 2005 until next yer. 
The application has no problem to access the different DB, but i have a problem with some reports hosted by report server.

With Sql Server 2005 i have to use the 8.0 version of the ReportViewer DLL, while with Sql Server 2008 i have to use the 10.0.

Is there anyway to manage both versions of the component in the same Visual Sutdio Solution/Project and choose runtime which version should be loaded? 
If it's not possible, do you have any alternatives in mind? (Obviously two project are not an option)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it is possible to use the Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms Version 9.0.0.0 which support both SSRS 2005 and SSRS 2008

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically load the assembly

[Dynamically Loading an assembly at Runtime](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/sridhar_subra/dynamicassemblymethod10132008214835pm/dynamicassemblymethod.aspx)

base it on something in the config file as to which it chooses.

I think you can also put something in the config file which determines at runtime which assembly to use, but that I'e never used and I don't know what to do there.

Comment: i looked at the example which, if i understood correctly, is a way to call a function from an assembly. That's useful, but i have an entire form which uses the ReportViewer classes from the assembly. I think I should look deeper in putting something in the config file.